# Unable to cast object...with datapicker

Tags: asp.net, .net, datapicker

I got the famous error *"InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code"
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'*
But I have not found the solution to my problem on the forum.

First I have no type "*string*" because my form contains only a datapicker.

Secondly, the field is a *smalldatetime* in my SQL database.

So, I don't know why it says that!?

The Error appears in the automatic file *"my_program.Web.g.vb"* when i input a date (from Datapicker) into my form.

[Error on my_programm.Web.g.vb]http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/854888Untitled.png

Here is the field of my form:

```
<dataFormToolkit:DataField>
<sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartingDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</dataFormToolkit:DataField>
```

Have you an idea for this problem?
Thank you in advance
Cordially

Comment: first convert your datetime value like this 

Convert.ToDateTime(StartingDate);

Answer (score 0):

It was very stupid

In addition to the conversion that I did as you suggested, I left a "StringLength(..)" tag dragged in another part of the code -__-

Really sorry for the inconvenience and thank you

Cordially